# PyODBC : can't open the driver even if it exists

Tags: python, sql-server, linux, pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm new to the linux world and I want to query a Microsoft SQL Server from Python. I used it on Windows and it was perfectly fine but in Linux it's quite painful.

After some hours, I finally succeed to install the Microsoft ODBC driver on Linux Mint with unixODBC.

Then, I set up an anaconda with python 3 environment.

I then do this :

```
import pyodbc as odbc

sql_PIM = odbc.connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};Server=XXX;Database=YYY;Trusted_Connection=Yes")
```

It returns :

```
('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

The thing I do not undertsand is that PyODBC seems to read the right filepath from odbcinst.ini and still does not work.

I went to "/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0" and the file actually exists !

So why does it tell me that it does not exist ?
Here are some possible clues :

- I'm on a virtual environment
- I need to have "read" rights because it's a root filepath

I do not know how to solve either of these problems.

Thanks !

Comment: It could be a missing library (a library used by libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0) or a LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue. Could you please share the result of the following command? `ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0`

Comment: Related: [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server can't open lib on pyodbc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41182415/55075).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also had the same problem on Ubuntu 14 after following the microsoft tutorial for [SQL Server Linux ODBC Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568454%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

The file exists and after running an ldd, it showed there were dependencies missing:

/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0)
/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version`CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by

after searching for a while I found its because Ubuntu's repo didnt have GLIBCXX on version 3.4.20, it was at 3.4.19.

I then added a repo to Ubuntu, updated it and forced it to upgrade libstdc++6

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Problem solved, tested with isql:

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

After that I tried testing using pdo_odbc (PHP), it then gave me the same driver not found error.
To solve this I had to create a symbolic link to fix `libodbcinst.so.2`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libodbcinst.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2
```

Comment: Thanks, I also fount his solution. than I have a problem with the connection to my database but that is another story. !

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem **'file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)'** on MAC OS with the following code

> cnxn = pyodbc.connect('**DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}**;SERVER=myServerIP,1433;DATABASE=myDBName;UID=sa;PWD=dbPassword')

after googling for two days, I cannot fix the issue even modify the freetds.conf, odbcinst.ini and odbc.ini

finally, I found the solution via replacing **DRIVER** value

> cnxn =
>   pyodbc.connect('**DRIVER={/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib}**;SERVER=myServerIP,1433;DATABASE=myDBName;UID=sa;PWD=dbPassword')

My dev environment

- MAC OS El Capitan
- python 3.6.1 in Anaconda

Comment: Hello please can you comment on this? I tried doing this this, and I am sure that the .dylib file exists in the folder which I specified. But it still gives me the error.     01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/home/environment/msodbcsql-17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)", can you suggest anything I may be doing wrong?

Comment: cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/home/environment/msodbcsql-17.1.0.1/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib};SERVER=XXXXX;DATABASE=DB;UID=XXXXXX;PWD=XXXXX) is what I had in my code

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error: pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver]Key value in connection string too long. (30119) (SQLDriverConnect)')

This is my connection string: DRIVER={/opt/ibm/iaccess/lib/libcwbodbc.dylib};SYSTEM=xxxxx;SIGNON=3;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxxx;

Comment: I can confirm that using absolute path to driver works on my MacOS machine. My driver is: "/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib".

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer that works for me [here](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1639). This is for python 2.7 (so may not work for those who are looking for a solution for python 3.x).

The suggested solution is to update libgcc: 4.8.5-2 --> 5.2.0-0

For updating libgcc, use this command

```
conda update libgcc
```

Comment: If you follow that link you get to the answer from nehalijwani that perfectly re-produces the problem and explains why updating libgcc fixes it. To summarize: pyodbc.so requires libstdc++.so. This file exists in conda, so it uses that version, instead of the system version. Unfortunately, libmsodbc.sql requires a later version than conda installs by default. Therefore, updating the conda libgcc allows the local reference to the conda version to work.

Answer (score 2):

The following suggestions may help to solve the problem:

- Make sure the drive configuration INI file exists `odbcinst -j` (check `odbcinst.ini`).
- Make sure the filepath to configured driver from your INI file (run: `odbcinst -j`) exist and has read and executable permission flags (`O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC`).
- If you still got *file not found* error, despite the file exists, the problem could be related to `libgcc` version mismatch as per [nehaljwani's GitHub comment](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1639#issuecomment-303195150). The solution is to update your `libgcc` by running `conda update libgcc` command.

  <sup>Related: [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server can't open lib on pyodbc while connecting on AWS E2 ubuntu instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41182415/55075).</sup>
- For macOS, see: [Installing ODBC via HomeBrew](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303331/22781).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a bit late, but I leave this scripts that worked for me.

My problem was the same as yours and I tested all the options such as changing the driver location, making a symbolic link, modify /etc/*.ini files, etc... nothing worked.

My problem, running python 3.6, pyodbc package in a docker container from alpine was the library **libssl1.0.0**

Here you will find [my installation script for pyodbc](https://github.com/nenetto/pymake/blob/69d35ee5913e28c89eb8472c0bfe9474c2935168/recipes/docker/MSSQL_drivers/MSSQL_drivers_install_debian_8_9.sh) [Debian 8 (alpine) docker image](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/b99b66406ebe728fb4da64548066ad0be6582e08/3.6/stretch/Dockerfile) using the driver v13

> DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}

The command I run for database connection was:

```
import pyodbc
connection_string = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
connection_string += 'SERVER={0};DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3};'.format(host,dbname,user,pwd)
connection = pyodbc.connect(connection_string)
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem after installing libssl1.0.0.

First, I setup my connection string in this way:

```
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib};   
    SERVER=myServerIP,1433;DATABASE=myDBName;UID=sa;PWD=dbPassword')
```

Then, I installed libssl1.0.0:

```
    echo "deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security jessie/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
    apt-get install libssl1.0.0
```

Finnaly, I setup the locales:

```
    apt-get -y install locales 
    echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
```

After doing these steps, my python module was able to find and connect to database.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue once..
1.try conda update libgcc(this is because pyodbc installed through pip and conda look for different versions of the file..)..this might have been fixed .....
link:https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1639
look for nehaljwani answer .

2.also check the version number of the odbc file correctly in /etc/odbcinst.ini and /etc/odbc.ini ...names should match and also the driver path.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem on a Mac mini M1 with macOS Mavericks. After installing the driver 18 from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16) which supports ARM it still did not work.

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_FILTERING=1 ACCEPT_EULA=Y brew install msodbcsql18 mssql-tools18
```

However isql on the commandline was able to connect to the database.

```
isql -v -k "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER=<MYSERVERNAME>;PORT=<MYPORT>;DATABASE=<MYDATABASE>;UID=<USERNAME>;PWD=<PASSWORD>"
```

Finally what did the trick was to uninstall pyodbc and install it again.

```
python -m pip uninstall pyodbc
python -m pip install pyodbc
```