# How to connect Scrapy spider deployed on Scrapinghub to a remote SQL server with SQLAlchemy and pyodbc?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy, pyodbc, scrapinghub

After trying to solve this problem on my own I need some help or nudge in right direction.

I wrote and deployed Scrapy spider on Scrapinghub. This spider collects some data and after finish saves that data to remote Microsoft SQL Server. I use SQLAlchemy as ORM and Pyodbc as a driver. 
For connecting to a DB  in spider code I use:

```
params = quote_plus('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};SERVER="server";DATABASE="db";UID="user";PWD="pass")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

On my local PC with Win10 all work well  - spider successfully connects to a remote DB and save data.
 But if I try to run this spider on Scrapinghub I get an error:
`DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")`

Seems like a problem with `DRIVER` part. I tried to change `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}` to a `DRIVER={SQL Server}` or `DRIVER={FreeTDS}` but still getting the same error `can't open lib 'lib_name' : file not found`.

Does Scrapinghub support connection to a Microsoft SQL Server at all? What driver parameters do I need to use in order to successfully connect?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you'll need [a custom Docker image](https://shub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deploy-custom-image.html) with the required ODBC drivers

Comment: Thank you for your response @paul trmbrth! I also use Scrapy-Splash with this spider, can I implement all desired functionality if I use a custom Docker image? Can you advise maybe I already can use a premade image? I not very familiar with Docker deployment and try to follow with this tutorial: https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/09/08/how-to-deploy-custom-docker-images-for-your-web-crawlers/ 
But unfortunately all this doesn't work as expected and now I have two problems :)

Comment: Using scrapy-splash is not a problem if you add a `pip install scrapy-splash` step in your Dockerfile. I don't know if Scrapinghub has pre-built image with those drivers. Best is to contact Scrapinghub support if they have one.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I'll try to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

> Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server' : file not found

Above error is usually related to misconfiguration or missing `odbcinst.ini` file.

Run `odbcinst -j` and verify whether `odbcinst.ini` does exist and it has the right driver path, e.g.

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib
```

Here is the example command creating user's config file (`~/.odbcinst.ini`):

```
printf "[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]\nDescription=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server\nDriver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.13.dylib\n" >> ~/.odbcinst.ini
```

See: [Installing the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux and macOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server).

<sup>If you're using Anaconda, checkout this issue: [ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server can't open lib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41182415/55075).</sup>